# Connect network camera from local machine to virtual machine

Tags: networking, router, virtualbox, camera

I have setup some network cameras on my a windows virtual machine. The camera is connected to a virtual machine router by an ethernet cable, and the virtual machine router is connected to the main router of my house. In the virtual machine, I'm able to capture the video stream from the camera. However, I would like my physical local windows machine connected to the camera as well. I want to know if there is a way that my physical machine is able to connect to the cameras inside the virtual machine without changing cables. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The Bridged Adapter connects through the host to whatever is your default network device that allocates IP addresses for your physical network. VirtualBox connects to one of your installed network cards and exchanges network packets directly; it bridges the virtual and physical networks.